# <select> HTML element pops up after being removed on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, select, safari

I've come across a rather strange bug that occurs in Safari on my iPhone 6/iOS 10.0.2 and in the iOS Simulator: after a `<select>` element has been used and removed from the DOM using javascript, it still pops up after a later event (not quite sure what triggers it though). Here's a very simple example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function removeSelect() {
                var parent = this.parentNode;
                if (parent != null) {
                    parent.removeChild(this);
                    document.getElementById("div").appendChild(document.createTextNode(parent.tagName));
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("div").appendChild(document.createTextNode("null parent"));
                }
            }
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById("sel").addEventListener("input", removeSelect);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div">
            <select id="sel">
                <option>first</option>
                <option>second</option>
                <option>third</option>
            </select>
            <button>ABC</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm testing this using the Apache2 server running on my iMac, accessing the page via WiFi from my iPhone, so basically `http://imac.local/test/test.html`. I don't expect the server has any kind of effect though.

As you can see, this page doesn't do much, simply removes the `<select>` from the DOM when the value changes. This "works" fine in any browser, i.e. the `<select>` disappears and `DIV` is appended after the button when a value is selected. In Safari on the iPhone, selecting a value does remove the `<select>` element and add the `DIV`, but when clicking the button afterwards the `<select>` menu is shown again with all the original options, and the text `null parent` is appended after `DIV` after the value is selected. This actually goes on forever and ever, i.e. the `<select>` is always triggered when clicking the button. The same happens in the iOS Simulator.

Note that clicking the `ABC` button prior to actually changing the value in the `<select>` has (as expected) absolutely no effect. Also note that if the javascript code is modified to *not* remove the `<select>`, the menu doesn't pop up when clicking the button.

Can someone please confirm that this actually happens the way I'm experiencing it, and does anyone have an idea about why this happens? Am I doing something wrong? If no, does someone know how I can prevent this from happening?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like a bug in Safari on iOS 10. I see a similar issue with the keyboard popping up over and over again after removing an `<input>` from the DOM.